# How do I set `gnutls-verify-error` to not check if certain hostname matches the certificate?

Tags: jabber, gnutls

I have the host `chat.deshackra.com` pointing to `tigase.im` (with a CNAME entry), and I want to use the starttls connection type for my jabber.el account, however the connection fails:

```
gnutls.c: [1] Note that the security level of the Diffie-Hellman key exchange has been lowered to 256 bits and this may allow decryption of the session data

jorge@chat.deshackra.com/emacs: connection lost: `STARTTLS negotiation failed: Certificate validation failed chat.deshackra.com, verification code 66'
```

So, how can I set [gnutls-verify-error](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs-gnutls.html#index-gnutls_002dverify_002derror-5) to ignore any error for my domain name?

**EDIT:** If I disable any encryption at all, I get this message:

```
Connecting to chat.deshackra.com:5222...
STARTTLS encryption required, but disabled/non-functional at our end
```

and my account is not connected.

Comment: From the linked documentation, it looks like you could potentially add your certificate into the `gnutls-trustfiles` list?

Comment: I have no cert file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As jabber.el started using the GnuTLS facility of Emacs before the variable `gnutls-verify-error` existed, it uses its own variable `jabber-invalid-certificate-servers`.  That variable contains a list of all servers for which certificate errors should be ignored.  Try this:

```
(setq jabber-invalid-certificate-servers '("chat.deshackra.com"))
```

Comment: setting that variable and reseting the connection-type to `starttls` did the work!